# No such factory: user (ArgumentError) but... it is defined. and using find_definitions() just finds duplicates... =\

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, factory-bot

So, I recently moved to bundler, and I'm having issues getting everything working again.

when I run bundle exec rake test:units, I get this error:

```
....../gems/factory_girl-1.2.4/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:327:in `factory_by_name': No such factory: user (ArgumentError)
```

and, I saw in a another stack overflow post that someone fixed the problem by adding

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

but, that errors in saying that I have duplicate definitions (which I don't, cause search) 
I even tried having only one factories file. but the error continued.

top of test_helper:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
require 'test_help'
  require "bundler/setup"
  Bundler.require(:test)
```

test group in gem file

```
group :test do
    gem "cucumber", "~>0.10.3"
    gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
    gem "launchy"
    gem "hpricot"
    gem "gherkin", "~>2.4.0"

    gem "capybara", "0.4.1.2"
    gem "rspec", "1.3.2"
    gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.2"
    gem "rspec-core"
    gem "rspec-expectations"

    gem "webrat", "0.7.0"
    gem "database_cleaner"

    gem "factory_girl", "1.2.4"
    gem "shoulda"
    gem "awesome_print"
    gem "cobravsmongoose"
end
```